# Adding multiple icons in QComboBox with QAbstractItemDelegate pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox

I wanted to set multiple icons in a single item in my QcomboBox. I think this can be implemented using the QAbstractItemDelegate, but I need some PyQt examples. The following link does give me an idea but I couldn't  get in running with Python :

[How to custome QCombobox with multiple comlumns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295950/how-to-custome-qcombobox-with-multiple-comlumns)

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you "couldn't get running", and explain what is wrong with it, what you expected to happen, etc.

Comment: Take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158731/items-disappears-from-combo-box-when-i-read-them-from-model) . It's not multiple icons in a single item but it is a working Python example of multi-checkable items in combo box.