# selecting items in a comboBox

Tags: python, combobox, qt-designer

How can I make my comboBox to allow me to select more than 1 item??

Or how can I simulate this behaviour with a comboBox from QtDesigner??

I would like the user to be able to click two or more items and I would be able to get the selected items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a list box, use the PyQt QListWidget:

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qlistwidget.html

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use `comboBox` to select more then one items here is how I've did it [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158731/items-disappears-from-combo-box-when-i-read-them-from-model). Also here is solution how to get what is selected [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186779/catch-mouse-button-pressed-signal-from-qcombobox-popup-menu)